# Thinking Python

Tags: python, optimization, formatting

I've been learning Python lately and tonight I was playing around with a couple of examples and I just came up with the following for fun:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
a = range(1,21)    # Range of numbers to print
max_length = 1     # String length of largest number
num_row = 5        # Number of elements per row

for l in a:
    ln = len(str(l))
    if max_length <= ln:
        max_length = ln

for x in a:
    format_string = '{:>' + str(max_length) + 'd}'
    print (format_string).format(x),
    if not x % num_row and x != 0:
        print '\n',
```

Which outputs the following:

```
 1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20
```

The script is doing what I want, which is to print aligned rows of 5 numbers per row, calculating the largest width plus one; but I'm almost convinced that there is either a:

- more "pythonic" way to do this
- more efficient way to do this.

I'm not an expert in big O by any means but I believe that my two for loops change this from an O(n) to at least O(2n), so I would really like to see if it's possible to combine them somehow.  I'm also not too keen on my `format_string` declaration, is there a better way to do that?  You aren't helping me cheat on homework or anything, I think this would pass most Python classes, I just want to wrap my head more around the Python way of thinking as I'm coming primarily from Perl (not sure if it shows :).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, an immediate down vote.  I didn't think it was that bad.  Any suggestions on how I could phrase the question better?

Comment: actually O(n) = O(2n), don't have to worry here :)

Comment: actually I think this question is pretty good, it's clear, it's descriptive, don't see why somebody downvoted it

Comment: FYI: O(2n) is O(n). Haha @RomanPekar was faster :P

Comment: :) my lack of big O understanding.  Wouldn't it become an issue if I were doing more to the list in either of the loops?

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of the very insightful answers, they have helped me quite a bit with my understanding of the Pythonic way of doing things.  I feel like my thinking is still a little too procedural, going to study the functional solution to my problem thoroughly.

Comment: Btw, you can nest formatters like this: `'{val:>{max_len}d}'.format(val=x, max_len=max_length)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You don't need to make `format_string` every time. Using [str.rjust](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.rjust), you don't need to use format string.
- Instead of using `x % num_row` (an element of list), use `i` (1-based index using `enumerate(a, 1)`). Think about a case `a = range(3, 34)`.

  - You can drop `i == 0` becaue `i` will never be `0`.
- `not x % num_row` is hard to understand. Use `x % num_row == 0` instead.

---

```
a = range(1,21)
num_row = 5

a = map(str, a)
max_length = len(max(a, key=len))
for i, x in enumerate(a, 1):
    print x.rjust(max_length),
    if i % num_row == 0:
        print
```

Comment: I really like this, both the use of rjust and max really clean up the code.  I had i == 0 in there because I was playing around with `range(20)` at first.  I need to go read up on enumerate now, and yes I agree that `x % num_row == 0` is easier to read than `not x % num_row`.

Comment: This might be better served by a follow up question but can you explain what the `max` is doing here.  When I run `max(a)` on the list of strings I get `'9'` telling me that `max` is calculating that the string `'9'` is the largest.  When I do it with the `key=len` key I get `'10'` which I can kind of understand, `'10'` is equal to the longest length of any string in the list.

Comment: @d34dh0r53, Without optional `key` specified, `max` return maximum value (for strings, lexicographical order..). With `key` specified, the return value of the `key` function applied to each item is used determine which item is larger.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do more pythonic calculation of maxlength :)

```
max_length = len(str(max(a)))
```

if your numbers could be negative or float

```
max_length = max([len(str(x)) for x in a])
```

Comment: @falsetru missed print, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Another entry. Just to add one with a little functional programming. :-)

```
n = 20
f = lambda x: str(x).rjust(len(str(n+1))) + (" " if x % 5 else "\n")
print "".join(map(f, range(1,n+1))),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is not more of a pessimization :-) but building on [falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18074289/1256452)'s answer a bit, we can use `itertools.groupby` to group each row by its row index.  Because `groupby` needs a key, we have to `enumerate` the values, and then discard the enumeration index afterward:

```
a = range(1,21)
num_row = 5

a = map(str, a)
max_length = len(max(a, key=len))
```

(same as before, but now:)

```
from itertools import groupby
# assumes / is integer division - use // if needed
# (I had // but SO formats it as a comment)
for _, g in groupby(enumerate(a), lambda x: x[0] / num_row):
    print ' '.join(x.rjust(max_length) for _, x in g)
```

Here each group `g` consists of all the (enumerated) values that make up each row, with their row number in front, so the inner generator for `' '.join` needs to discard the row index (`for _, x in g`).  That leaves just the string `x`, which gets right adjusted as before, and then the right-adjusted strings are `join`ed with spaces between them.  The resulting string is ready to be printed as a complete line.